# Rails preview result of block without persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I'm currently working on adding some management of orders in a Rails ecommerce application.

The desired flow is that you enter an *editing session* for an order, you then make proposed changes to the items of an order ( this could be things like cancelling an item, adding an item etc ) these changes are then reflected in the UI, e.g. order totals update, balances change. But none of these should actually be persisted until the user presses save.

I'm looking for some guidance on the most correct *Rails* way to handle this sort of pattern, the difficult for me being that the models involved are quite complex and nested, the actions involved e.g. in cancelling an item are on the surface a simple method call but for a full audit trail more stuff is going on in the background.

The approaches I've so far considered are

1. Making this a pure presentational challenge and just adjusting the numbers shown on screen based on whats selected ( my main worry with this is when it gets more complicated e.g. adding discounts, multi currency etc where theres already quite a lot of logic built around the orders to calculate these values and I dont think its a very trivial problem to then just amend these for presentation without going through the full process and so could lead to discrepancies )
2. Using some sort of draft model through the [has_draft](https://github.com/rubiety/has_draft) or [draftsman](https://github.com/copasetickid/draftsman) gems, again its the nested nature of our modelling and complexity around state management which worries me with this approach
3. Ensuring that whatever process we use for these amends works transactionally. Separating the UI out  from the process to the point where our UI almost creates an *instruction set* which is used in our backend to apply the changes and making sure that these changes can be carried out as part of a transaction then aborted if necessary, this would allow us to maintain our complex logic and figure everything out in the exact same way it would be carried out when the user wants to persist the changes but feels like we're abusing the [Active Record Transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions.html)if we're purposefully rolling back as we only wanted to preview the changes, also not sure how dangerous that would be.

Any insight into where a similar problem has been solved before, if theres some sort of pattern that I'm missing which could help with this feature would be greatly appreciated, apologies if the question seems convoluted, its quite to hard to express all details of the feature and difficulties around it whilst trying to keep succinct.

***EDIT***
Having re-read my question I think I've put across in quite a complicated way, I was trying to give the entire problem scope i.e. what outcome we want but I think in trying to provide alternate approaches and why they dont work I've made more complicated.
I believe something along the lines of approach 3 is what we will need with the route of previewing changes.
Then the problem statement becomes given a set of methods to be called, how can we preview the result of those without persisting anything afterwards. The approach described above using a transaction could look something like

```rb
new_total = nil
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @order.amend(instruction_set)
  new_total = @order.total
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
render json: new_total
```

I'm just concerned by the safety of this.

Comment: How about creating an order duplicate in the DB for the editing session. Then you can run all the models and normal procedures. If the order is saved, the copy becomes the main order. If the mods are cancelled, you delete the copy and restore the saved one.

Comment: @Casper I definitely dont think like thats a bad route to go, the only issue with it is the associated records involved in the process, I considered using something like the clowne gem to create this complex duplicate. The sort of things I'm talking about here are the fact an order might have many items, many payment charges, refunds, associated currency rates, discounts etc all of which can play a part in calculating any new numbers. I definitely wouldn't cast this aside as an approach though, alternative to the transaction one I've discussed above.